# Postgres - Match as much as possible of beginning of search parameter

Tags: postgresql, search, large-files

I have a postgres table that contains a very large number of numerals of various lengths. For example, the first column of the table will look like this:

1. 1
2. 12
3. 13
4. 134
5. 135
6. 136
7. 1362
8. 1363
9. ...

I need postgres to return the row that matches as much of the beginning of a given numeral as possible. For example, the numeral "1358302" needs to match row 5 ("135") and "1362304" needs to match row 7 ("1362").

What SQL could I use to achieve this?

(the numerals aren't sorted there permanently yet, so if you need to switch the data type between integer or string for simplicity/performance sake, I can still do that!)

Comment: hmm, "1362304" needs to match row 7 ("1362"), right?

Comment: This problem is typically referred to as a longest prefix match. Searching for information using that term may be helpful. See http://www.google.com.au/search?q=postgresql+longest+prefix+match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT n
FROM your_table
WHERE n IN (
    select $1/(10^i)::int8 from generate_series(0,floor(log($1))::int) i
)
ORDER BY n DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I didn't think of generating the IN clause that way. I've shamelessly incorporated your code in my answer. (With credit to you though.)

Answer (score 1):

Brute force always works.

```
select max(n)
from your_table
where n in (1, 13, 136, 1362, 13623, 136230, 1362304);
```

You can generate the IN clause in application code or in a stored procedure.

Or, as filiprem did, generate it in a sub select.  After loading a table with a million integers and looking at the execution plans, this seems to have the best balance of flexibility and performance. ORDER BY is expensive on big tables, and I think it's unnecessary in this case; the longest match will be the largest number. (Assuming non-negative integers.)

```
SELECT max(n)
FROM numerals
WHERE n IN (
    select 1362304/(10^i)::int8 
    from generate_series(0,floor(log(1362304))::int) i
);
```

The literal value 1362304 occurs in two places. Replace it with a parameter.

You can probably halve the run time again by doing an inner join on the subquery instead of using the subquery in the WHERE clause.

```
with prefixes as (
  select 1362304/(10^i)::int8 prefix
  from generate_series(0,floor(log(1362304))::int) i
)
select max(n)
from numerals 
inner join prefixes 
        on prefixes.prefix = numerals.n
```

This last version runs in 0.22ms (not a typo) on a million rows.

Comment: `ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1` in terms of performance is equivalent (or even faster) than `max`.

Comment: @filiprem: The version I posted, using MAX(n) and your subselect, ran in 44ms on a million rows.  Your version, using ORDER BY...LIMIT 1 took 780 ms. Erwin's version, 960ms.

Comment: Correction: Erwin's version ran in 333ms with Gavin's suggested index. I'll take another look at this later. I haven't used the optional operator classes before.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following demo.

Temporary table for testing:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE nr(id int, nr numeric);
INSERT INTO nr VALUES
(1,1),(2,12),(3,13),(4,134),(5,135),
(6,136),(7,1362),(8,1363);
```

Query:

```
SELECT nr
FROM   nr
WHERE  '1362235' ~~ (nr::text || '%')
ORDER  BY length(nr::text) DESC
LIMIT  1;
```

Delivers the longest match as requested. Operating with strings (not numbers) simplifies the task. You can change the data type in your table or you can cast the values in the query like I did.

If you need it to be **fast**, change the type to `text` and index `nr`. A search like that can utilize a plain btree index (default) and will be *very* fast.

```
CREATE INDEX nr_nr_idx ON nr (nr);
```

If your database locale is not 'C' or 'POSIX', use [`text_pattern_ops`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-opclass.html) as @Gavin commented, or the `LIKE` operator (`~~`) cannot use it even for the start of the column, because sort order is locale-specific.

```
CREATE INDEX nr_nr_idx ON nr (nr text_pattern_ops);
```

If you need your table column to be a numeric type, there is another option. Use an [index on an expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-expressional.html) like so:

```
CREATE INDEX nr_nr_idx ON nr ((nr::text) text_pattern_ops);
```

The above query can utilize an index such as this one, because the expression matches the index expression.

Comment: probably worth doing CREATE INDEX nr_nr_idx ON nr(nr text_pattern_ops) if you have much data.